# Issue with changing images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm a novice and learning coding to boost my skills. I have been working on a basic page and have run into a problem. I have 3 images on the page. Each one has a Before and after button which has a onclick to change the image to show original photo and then the edited photo. I managed to make it work for 1 photo, however, when I wrote the functions for the 2nd and 3rd image, all 3 button sets are only changing the 3rd photo. This photo cycles through all 6 images depending on which button is pressed.:) My Codepen link is below.

https://codepen.io/Rayhaan2k9/pen/BaLaOYJ

```js
var img = document.getElementById("Yusuf-log");

function before1() {
  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/DpwkckU.jpg';
}

function after1() {
  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/foO4uWu.jpg';
}

var img = document.getElementById("Yusuf field");

function before2() {
  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/dd6WEZu.jpg';
}

function after2() {
  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/A6KAOZz.jpg';
}

var img = document.getElementById("Zak-mosque");

function before3() {
  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/O2cjLB7.jpg';
}

function after3() {
  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/Mpnx3rP.jpg';
}
```

```css
img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<img id="Yusuf-log" src="https://i.imgur.com/DpwkckU.jpg" alt="Yusuf Log">

<div class="button-area1">
  <button onclick="before1()">Before</button>
  <button onclick="after1()">After</button>
</div>

<img id="Yusuf field" src="https://i.imgur.com/dd6WEZu.jpg" alt="Yusuf Field">

<!-- button area -->
<div class="button-area2">
  <button onclick="before2()">Before</button>
  <button onclick="after2()">After</button>
</div>

<img id="Zak-mosque" src="https://i.imgur.com/O2cjLB7.jpg" alt="Zakariyya Mosque">

<!-- button area -->
<div class="button-area3">
  <button onclick="before3()">Before</button>
  <button onclick="after3()">After</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring same variable name `img` for all three photos so it only works for the last `img` variable. Use a different name instead will solve your issue.

```
var img1 = document.getElementById("Yusuf-log");
var img2 = document.getElementById("Yusuf-field");
var img3 = document.getElementById("Zak-mosque");

    function before1(){
        img1.src='https://i.imgur.com/DpwkckU.jpg';
    }

    function after1(){
        img1.src='https://i.imgur.com/foO4uWu.jpg';
        
    }

    ..
```

Here is the updated [code](https://codepen.io/KaungKZ/pen/eYdYPNm?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

you should add the img variable within function,

```
function before1() {
  var img = document.getElementById("Yusuf-log");
  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/DpwkckU.jpg';
}

function after1() {
  var img = document.getElementById("Yusuf-log");
  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/foO4uWu.jpg';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var img = document.getElementById("Yusuf-log");

function before1() {
  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/DpwkckU.jpg';
}

function after1() {
  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/foO4uWu.jpg';
}

var img2 = document.getElementById("Yusuf_field");

function before2() {
  img2.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/dd6WEZu.jpg';
}

function after2() {
  img2.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/A6KAOZz.jpg';
}

var img3 = document.getElementById("Zak-mosque");

function before3() {
  img3.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/O2cjLB7.jpg';
}

function after3() {
  img3.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/Mpnx3rP.jpg';
}
```

```css
img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<img id="Yusuf-log" src="https://i.imgur.com/DpwkckU.jpg" alt="Yusuf Log">

<div class="button-area1">
  <button onclick="before1()">Before</button>
  <button onclick="after1()">After</button>
</div>

<img id="Yusuf_field" src="https://i.imgur.com/dd6WEZu.jpg" alt="Yusuf Field">

<!-- button area -->
<div class="button-area2">
  <button onclick="before2()">Before</button>
  <button onclick="after2()">After</button>
</div>

<img id="Zak-mosque" src="https://i.imgur.com/O2cjLB7.jpg" alt="Zakariyya Mosque">

<!-- button area -->
<div class="button-area3">
  <button onclick="before3()">Before</button>
  <button onclick="after3()">After</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute can contain only one value as you did it right by the first and the third image, you forgot to add a dash to the second.

```html
<img id="Yusuf-field" src="https://i.imgur.com/dd6WEZu.jpg" alt="Yusuf Field">
```

Also by the Javascript you have initialized the variable `img` and re-initialized it again. You could use the previous answer and fetch your elements each time within the function and initialize your variable `img` **or** add a number to make each of them distinct like the example below

```js
var ìmg1 = document.getElementById("Yusuf-log");
var ìmg2 = document.getElementById("Yusuf-field");
var ìmg3 = document.getElementById("Zak-mosque");
```